# Draw layout after 100% loaded WebView in this layout

Tags: android, android-listview, webview, android-webview

How to draw layout (row) which contains ***WebView*** only if ***WebView*** in this layout is 100% loaded? I want to deal with loading on scroll but it's not working properly on start when my ***WebView*** with ***wrap_content*** attribute hasn't loaded yet. I tried to apply ***min_height*** for ***WebView*** or put ***WebView*** in ***LinearView*** with ***min_height*** but it's not doing well.

My loadData() function:

```
public void loadData() {
    viewOrders = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getOrders();
        }
    };
    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,    
          "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
}
```

My getView() function:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }
    Order o = items.get(position);
    if (o != null) {
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_textView);
        WebView web_view = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_webView);
        if (name != null) {
            name.setText("Name: "+o.getOrderName());                            }
        if(web_view != null){
            //web_view.setText(o.getOrderLink());
            web_view.loadUrl(o.getOrderLink());
            web_view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            web_view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            web_view.setInitialScale(30);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```